# Passing data from one page to another in Next 13

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13

I have a form, the function which is supposed to happen is generating a Card using the data enetered into the form which will then be printed out. I have figured out the priting part,but I am stuck at getting the data from the form to the card display page. I have done something similar in react, where is used the useNavigate hook and its accompanying state prop  to pass around data. Is there something equivalent to that in Next 13?

I have tried out the stuff in the docs ie; using the router from next/router and next/naviagtion  but they havent worked out for me

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from page to another through query parameters, and consume the data using [useSearchParams](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params).

OR

You can lift the state of your page to a higher order component to set and consume the data from both the pages.